# TRACE32 debugging --Tracing Function Call

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, trace32

How to know which function has called a particular instruction using trace32 ? ARM based.

It's like I know that this instruction X has some error. How can I trace back to which function in the code executed this instruction X.

Also how to learn more about using trace32
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the encoding of your instruction, you can search through your memory for the instruction with the `Data.Find` command.

E.g: To find inside the address range 0x10000--0x1FFFF the instruction "asreq r0,r12,#0x1F" encoded Thumb2 you can use:

```
Data.find P:0x10000--0x1FFFF %Long 0x01A00FCC
```

Other option: Record your application with ETM trace (if this is available with your chip and Lauterbach tool) and make a text search trough the recording. E.g.:

```
WinPOS ,,,,,,TraceList
Trace.List List.CODE List.ADDRESS List.ASM 
WinFIND "asreq   r0,r12,#0x1F" TraceList
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need trace in your case. Just set a breakpoint and then look at the call stack:

```
# set breakpoint
Break.Set P:<address>
# go until breakpoint is hit
Go
WAIT !STATE.RUN()
# display call stack
Frame
```

To learn how to use TRACE32 check your TRACE32 installation, e.g. "training_debugger.pdf".